# How do I use the gamescene.sks file?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've been making a game primarily using code to create all nodes and I'm trying to figure out how to use the GameScene.sks file.

I read about an answer that said I could add it in the GameViewController.swift file but that isn't working.

This is what my code looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size) }
```

and this is what I'm trying:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene.sks") }
```

but the scene isn't changing, even though my gamescene.sks file has a different color background and some nodes. None are showing up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget the braces. I added them for you in your question.

Comment: Why aren't you using the default code that Xcode generates when you create a new SpriteKit project?

Comment: thank you CeceXX, and @0x141E because I started out first by following a tutorial at raywenderlich.com and they changed the code and I just kind of went with it.

Comment: The default code uses GameScene.sks to set up the initial scene.

Comment: I see, I'll create a new project to see what that looks like and apply it to my project, thank you!

Comment: @0x141E you can add that as an answer and I'll accept it